# Is this question really off topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

I am asking a reason from the scope of Hinduism for this question. Why did my question got closed?

[why are eggs not consumed in hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2601/)

Comment: There has been a discussion about questions related to food: [Too Many “Is X Vegetarian” Questions](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/263/too-many-is-x-vegetarian-questions). Personally, I don't think the question was repetitive though similar questions exist. Others don't seem to think so..

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Now *I've closed your question as a duplicate* to a canonical question which is related to yours so that we don't have the same question with different food item names.

---

Your question was closed by me and one other user. The reason is defined already which says

> "This question does not appear to be about Hindu religion, within the
>   scope defined in the help center."

Initially your question was :

> why is eating egg considered as non-vegetarian habit in hinduism

So attaching word Hinduism behind the question won't make it really about Hinduism, no doubt other users altered the title (7 revisions already) but still, your question doesn't add anything to the site, as [@Bharat pointed out](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268/is-this-question-really-off-topic/269#comment723_268), its just another question about a food item which is already asked many times.

Hence you shouldn't feel discouraged with this, we are still in the beta stage. Many of the rules are yet to be decided, that what will be on topic, off topic, i.e scope for the site which will help us to keep the site neat and on topic with rich content which can be referred by future visitors. We don't want to scare them off with tons of similar food questions.

For now you can refer a community post over this, feel free to edit the answer or post a new answer if you want to.

[What are Tamasic, Rajasic and Sattvic foods?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2659/) [Intended to be community wiki]

Comment: now i have edited my question can i get it opened now

Comment: @agharehanabbas I'll decide soon.. mostly it wont but dont worry, you are not losing anything.. the question will stay as is...